# many to many relation and four table

Tags: hibernate, jpa, many-to-many

I use jpa with hibernate implementation

I have a many to many relation.

```
@Entity
public class ServicePackages {

    ...
    @ManyToMany
    private List<Services> services;
    ...
}


@Entity
public class Services
    ...
    @ManyToMany
    private List<ServicePackages> servicePackages;
}
```

Why i get 4 table ?

service_packages
servies
services_service_packages 
service_packages_services

I was thinking to get 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A M-N relation should be marked as bidirectional to get a single join table. You currently have two independent M-N relations, and so the join table will not be shared, and you get 2.

Define `mappedBy` on one side of the M-N relation to make it bidirectional. Such as

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy="servicePackages")
private List<Services> services;
```

Comment: there is any impact about who do persisting?

Comment: setting BOTH sides of the relation is the thing to bear in mind.